# Bootstrap styles does't work (no collapse)

Tags: java, jsp, bootstrap-4

The Collapse option doesn't work with my code. I took the example from the Bootstrap web.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/album/

I have Java project with this example in the .jsp file 1:1. Everything works, all required .js and .css files are included and when I start the app on my localhost and display source code I am able to open all linked libraries - so I suppose application knows about everything needed.

Could you please help me with the problem?

[image: Screen of my workspace]

[image: Screen of my workspace 2]

There are shown all .css and .js files references and project structure in screenshot files. The rest of the code is 1:1 with the example from the web.

I checked other similar topics but there were no satisfying answers.

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">

    <title>Album example for Bootstrap</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/album/">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/album.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<header>
    <div class="collapse bg-dark" id="navbarHeader">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-7 py-4">
                    <h4 class="text-white">About</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Add some information about the album below, the author, or any other background context. Make it a few sentences long so folks can pick up some informative tidbits. Then, link them off to some social networking sites or contact information.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 offset-md-1 py-4">
                    <h4 class="text-white">Contact</h4>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Follow on Twitter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Like on Facebook</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Email me</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark box-shadow">
        <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="mr-2"><path d="M23 19a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V8a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4l2-3h6l2 3h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2z"></path><circle cx="12" cy="13" r="4"></circle></svg>
                <strong>Album</strong>
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHeader" aria-controls="navbarHeader" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<main role="main">

    <section class="jumbotron text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">Album example</h1>
            <p class="lead text-muted">Something short and leading about the collection below—its contents, the creator, etc. Make it short and sweet, but not too short so folks don't simply skip over it entirely.</p>
            <p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary my-2">Main call to action</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary my-2">Secondary action</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                                </div>
                                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                                </div>
                                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                                </div>
                                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                                </div>
                                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                                </div>
                                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                                </div>
                                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                                </div>
                                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                                </div>
                                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                                </div>
                                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</main>

<footer class="text-muted">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="float-right">
            <a href="#">Back to top</a>
        </p>
        <p>Album example is &copy; Bootstrap, but please download and customize it for yourself!</p>
        <p>New to Bootstrap? <a href="../../">Visit the homepage</a> or read our <a href="../../getting-started/">getting started guide</a>.</p>
    </div>
</footer>

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"/>" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/popper.min.js"/>"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/holder.min.js"/>"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include code *as code*.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know about `.jsp` but when you add CDN, its works fine

I just replaced your link and script file with CDN

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
    <title>Album example for Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/album/">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<header>
    <div class="collapse bg-dark" id="navbarHeader">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-7 py-4">
                    <h4 class="text-white">About</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Add some information about the album below, the author, or any other background context. Make it a few sentences long so folks can pick up some informative tidbits. Then, link them off to some social networking sites or contact information.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 offset-md-1 py-4">
                    <h4 class="text-white">Contact</h4>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Follow on Twitter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Like on Facebook</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Email me</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark box-shadow">
        <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="mr-2"><path d="M23 19a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V8a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4l2-3h6l2 3h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2z"></path><circle cx="12" cy="13" r="4"></circle></svg>
                <strong>Album</strong>
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHeader" aria-controls="navbarHeader" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<main role="main">

    <section class="jumbotron text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">Album example</h1>
            <p class="lead text-muted">Something short and leading about the collection below—its contents, the creator, etc. Make it short and sweet, but not too short so folks don't simply skip over it entirely.</p>
            <p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary my-2">Main call to action</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary my-2">Secondary action</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                                </div>
                                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                                </div>
                                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                                </div>
                                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                                </div>
                                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                                </div>
                                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                                </div>
                                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                                </div>
                                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                                </div>
                                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                                </div>
                                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</main>

<footer class="text-muted">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="float-right">
            <a href="#">Back to top</a>
        </p>
        <p>Album example is &copy; Bootstrap, but please download and customize it for yourself!</p>
        <p>New to Bootstrap? <a href="../../">Visit the homepage</a> or read our <a href="../../getting-started/">getting started guide</a>.</p>
    </div>
</footer>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```